# Curve fitting the cross sectional area of a cake.

Tags: calculus, volume, area

For my final Calculus project I have to find the area of a Bundt cake through the use of cross sectional areas. (Cakeulus)

While most seniors in High School who run into this popular calculus project may do the minimal amount possible; I wish to take this a step forward.

I cut a cross section of the cake and remade it in Photoshop

[image]

Both axis are in inches. Each interval is 1 inch. The origin represents the center bottom of the plate.

I used some software to find the points of about 180 points on the curve.

[Here it is on a google sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r4m6dNo8AURDtJw3-VgVj_Nr-9YgWx8uGMDlGxC4x4k/edit?usp=sharing)

To find the volume of the entire cake by rotating the curve around the y axis, I need to find a function that can most accurately fit to the curve I have at hand.

I understand that I could use something like an ellipse, but is there any other method by which I can find a curve that "perfectly" fits my data? The size of the equation would not be an issue I just want a high level of accuracy.

Many other students are just using a quadratic to keep things simple but that ignores the curved nature of the base of the cake.

Any help would be appreciated in finding the best function that I can then rotate along the y axis.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you could get an excellent approximation of the area without using a "curve" to fit your data. You say you have about $180$ points on the curve. That means you have a *polygon* that closely approximates the cross-section of the bundt cake. That's all you need.

[Pappus's Centroid Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem#The_second_theorem) (the second one) says the volume of the cake is the product of the area of the slice and the length of the circle that the centroid makes when it revolves around the $y$-axis. You can use [the shoelace formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) to find the area from your polygon's points, and [another, similar formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon) to find the location of the centroid. (Note that the centroid reference gives another formula for the area.) Finding the arc length made by the centroid is trivial, so the volume will be easy.

From the links I gave you should be able to use a spreadsheet (such as google sheets) to find the area and centroid, and the rest is easy. Ask if you need more help. This should easily give you high credit for your project. If your teacher asks how calculus was used, point to Pappus's Centroid Theorem (which was discovered by geometry but these days is used in calculus class and justified by calculus).

---

By the way, I exported your Data to MS Excel and got these values:

Area=$7.170317894$ (actually, the negative of that, since your points are in "backwards," clockwise order)

Centroid= $(3.072863031, 1.504220763)$

(These figures are corrected from a previous version of this answer.) I'll leave the final volume calculation to you.

---

If you are serious about finding "a curve that 'perfectly' fits my data" and it is true that "the size of the equation would not be an issue I just want a high level of accuracy", the polygon leads you to a perfect answer. This particular answer works since no two consecutive $x$-values in your data are equal, so none of the bordering line segments is vertical. Here is a relation, using a point-point form of the equation of a line:

$$\left(2.7263985\le x<2.8254118 \quad\text{and}\quad
 \frac{y-3.1299872}{x-2.7263985}=\frac{3.1291170-3.1299872}{2.8254118-2.7263985}\right)$$
$$\text{or}$$
$$\left(2.8254118\le x<2.9258595 \quad\text{and}\quad
 \frac{y-3.1291170}{x-2.8254118}=\frac{3.0881827-3.1291170}{2.9258595-2.8254118}\right)$$
$$\text{or}$$
$$\vdots$$

If you want to avoid the logical operators "and" and "or" there are numeric ways of simulating them, but that would make the relation even longer. Note that I did not use the usual "definition by cases" of a function since the relation is not a function: there are two values of $y$ for all values of $x$ between $1.5996108$ and $4.5847140$. You could use "definition by cases" of two functions if you use a parametric form of the relation rather than a Cartesian one, or if you define the upper and the lower curves separately.

Comment: Wow, this is incredibly fascinating! I used an ellipse and rotated it about the Y axis to get a rouge estimation of the volume.

I do want to use Pappus's Centroid Theorem, however volume by rotation about the y axis is required as part of the project.

I went ahead with the calculations for the area and centroid with the meathod you described and arrived at the same answer. 

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with point-point form of the equation of a line. Franky I have no idea how to even rotate that equation about the y axis.

Comment: Perhaps I could use the Fourier Series mentioned by another user? Would I be able to rotate that about the Y axis? I still have yet to try the parametric form or the "upper and lower" curve method. As much as I love math, this seemingly simple problem has become difficult and daunting.

Comment: @ZaidMansuri: Equations of a line that goes through the points $(a_1,b_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2)$ are $\frac{y-b_1}{x-a_1}=\frac{b_2-b_1}{a_2-a_1}$, and $y=\left(\frac{b_2-b_1}{a_2-a_1}\right)(x-a_1)+b_1$. These point-point forms come from the fact that the slope between any two points on a given line are equal, so slopes between the two given points and between one of them and $(x,y)$ are equal. Without more context I'm not sure how to answer your other points.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Fourier series to represent the shape of the cross section of the cake

$$
r(\theta) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(a_k \sin(k\theta) + b_k \cos(k\theta))
$$
One would have to set an origin inside the cross section of the cake. With some luck, the function $r$ will be one-valued and the expansion could be used.